# BATCH input redirection operator

Tags: file, batch-file, command, redirect, echo

```
set a=file
if exist "folder\%a%" ( 
 set /p x= < "folder\%a%" 
 echo %x% 
)
```

i've been writing batch files for a long time, but i don't get it why
this code does not work. Im expecting the code to echo out the content of the
%a%. but all it returns is the status of ECHO (**Echo is ON**)

the %a% (file) contains a string ('keyword') which is expected to be echoed out when
set in %x%

i even tried to put an extension (.txt) but still it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work, because the complete parenthesis block (and also echo %x%) is evaluated before the "set /p" will be executed, you could change to delayed expansion.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set a=file
if exist "folder\%a%" ( 
 set /p x= < "folder\%a%" 
 echo !x!
)
```

**[EDIT]**

This code also accepts exclamation marks in the filename

```
set "a=folder\foo!bar.txt"
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
if exist "!a!" (
  set /p x= < "!a!"
  echo !x!
)
```

Comment: may i ask you what does delayed expansion means?

Comment: If %a% contains ! (example "foo!bar.txt") then your code breaks

Comment: %var% expanded the line or parenthesis block in the moment of reading, before any command of the line or block is executed. The delayed expansion must be enabled and then it expands the !var! like %var%, but in the moment just before excuting each command of a line or block, also "set /?" explains it

Comment: @Anders: I changed the code, so it will also work, if %a% contains exclamation marks

Comment: haha sorry for making you explain kinda got confused after typing set /? that's why i asked you :P .thanks

Comment: @jeb: name the file "foo!bar!.txt", breaks again

Comment: @Anders, I suspect that you are pointing out the edge case that causes delayed expansion to be off by default.

Comment: @RBerteig: yes, delayed expansion does not mix well with filesystem paths, but it is usually possible to turn it off when handling paths and then turn it back on etc It is pretty much impossible to create a batch file that is able to deal with %!'^ in any combination

Comment: @Anders: "foo!bar!.txt" works fine, as expected. also "foo^!bar!10%%.txt" (doubling the percent sign is neccessary)

Answer (score 1):

```
if exist "folder\%a%" ( 
 set /p x=< "folder\%a%"
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION&echo !x!&ENDLOCAL
)
```

This is basically the same code as jeb, but ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION will not affect the path, so filenames with ! will still work (% will probably not work, but that is a general problem with batch files and filenames)

`set /p x= < .\somefile` is a bit of a hack, you might want to consider using `FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A` ... but FOR will read each line unless you put a if inside the DO. So you end up with something ugly like this if you only want the first line:

```
set eof=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('type "folder\%a%" 2^>nul') DO (
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION&(if "!eof!"=="0" (echo.%%A))&ENDLOCAL
    set eof=1
)
```

Comment: A FOR-Loop can be break with a goto :label